# When I log into different redis nodes, why do I get different node information

Tags: redis-cluster

environment：
redis:redis-7.2.3.
I built three servers to set up redis cluster  （Three master and three subordinate structure）.
But when I log in different redis node, I get the information of different nodes, specific to the different slot information, is this why? （The three machines are interconnected).

node2:6379@16379 myself,master - 0 1702864932000 4 connected 5462-10922
node2:6379@16379 master - 0 1702865552935 4 connected 5462-16383

172.18.102.194 node1.
172.18.102.195 node2.
172.18.102.196 node3.

Below is the node information of node two.
node2:6379> cluster nodes
node2:6379@16379 myself,master - 0 1702864932000 4 connected 5462-10922
node2:6380@16380 slave 0 1702864933576 5 connected
node3:6380@16380 slave 0 1702864934578 1 connected
node1:6380@16380 slave 0 1702864933000 4 connected
node1:6379@16379 master - 0 1702864934000 1 connected 0-5461
node3:6379@16379 master - 0 1702864935580 5 connected

Below is the node information of node three.
node3:6379> cluster nodes
node3:6379@16379 myself,master - 0 1702865552000 5 connected
node1:6379@16379 master - 0 1702865553000 1 connected 0-5461
node2:6380@16380 slave 0 1702865551932 5 connected
node3:6380@16380 slave 0 1702865551000 1 connected
node1:6380@16380 slave 0 1702865553937 4 connected
node2:6379@16379 master - 0 1702865552935 4 connected 5462-16383

I performed on 2 node CLUSTER DELSLOTSRANGE 10926 16383 but node3 if not synchronous CLUSTER node information.